# I get the function code in the alert box, why is this?

Tags: javascript

When I run this script I get the speak function code in the alert box.  It should be "Hello!" not function() {alert("Hello!")}; .  I use alert because I seem to like it better over console.log for learning.  The script works fine without the speak function.

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
  this.firstname=firstname;
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.age=age;
  this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
  this.newlastname=newlastname;
  this.speak=function(){alert("Hello!")};
}

var myFather=new person("John", "Doe", 45, "blue");
var myMother=new person("Sally","Rally", 48,"green");

function newlastname(new_lastname) {
  this.lastname=new_lastname;
}

myMother.newlastname("Doe");
alert(myMother.lastname);
alert(myMother.speak);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
myMother.speak();
```

For functions that take in strings, (like, `alert()`), if you pass in a function, it will take that to mean the source code of the function. So, when you passed `myMother.speak` into `alert`, it took the source code, hence the result you were seeing.

(If anyone can expand on this further or provide helpful links, feel free to edit this answer)

Comment: Thank you, I also took out the alert and just replaced it with myMother.speak(); since it was a double alert.  Thank you again

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, so I changed the answer to avoid having a double alert.

Comment: You might expand on this to explain why, for new JS programmers who find it in the future.

Comment: Done. Added an explanation detailing my understanding of what happened in the OPs original code.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the function code in the alert box, why is this?

well thats cause your are referencing a function, not calling it, it seems that `alert()` may be calling the `toString()` function on the parameter, and calling `tostring()` on a function reference seems to be returning the source as a string, hence when you alert you get the source, Though this is just a hunch since alert seems to be implemented natively so I can't really say how its implemented.

Nor can I say this behavior is consistent among all browsers.